# How to group by in linq at second level

Tags: linq

```
public class ShipmentItem
{
  public int? ShipmentId { get; set; }
  public int? TotalCountShipmentItems { get; set; }          
  public List<PurchaseOrderItem> ShipmentItemList { get; set; }
}
public class PurchaseOrderItem
{
  public int itemId{get;set}
  public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int? TotQuantity { get; set; }                
}
```

I want the result in the format

```
 data: [
    {
      ShipmentId : 15,
      TotalCountShipmentItems : 4,
      ShipmentItemList : [
        {
         itemId: 10,
         ItemNumber: 1012,
         Description : desss,
        TotQuantity : 20,/*sum of all items of id 10*/
        },
       {
         itemId: 11,
         ItemNumber: 1013,
         Description : d333s,
        TotQuantity : 50,/*sum of all items of id 11*/
        }
]
}]
```

I want result group by shipmentId then by Group by ItemId 
tried to group by but not with luck on the second level but not working 
It will cause sequence issue

Where am I making mistake? Can we not group it on geting list or before?

Comment: There's no need for grouping anywhere. What you show here is just one `ShipmentItem` object including its `ShipmentItemList`. A simple query with `Include` will do.

Comment: There isn't any reference between `ShipmentItem` and `PurchaseOrderItem`. how are you even fetching the items. I mean how wd you get to know that Item X is a part of Shipment Y.

Comment: @Sumitraj See `ShipmentItemList`.

Comment: @GertArnold don't you think  `ShipmentItem` and `PurchaseOrderItem`  ahould be related with id's. If there isn't any, i don't think he can even apply `.Include()`.